# Clean way to collect into matrix

Tags: rust

I'd like to split and collect this strangely-shaped vector

```rust
let v = vec![
    0, 1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6, 7,

    8, 9,
    10, 11,
    12, 13,
];
```

into these two matrices:

```rust
let v1 = vec![
    vec![0, 1, 2, 3],
    vec![4, 5, 6, 7],
];

let v2 = vec![
    vec![8, 9],
    vec![10, 11],
    vec![12, 13],
];
```

<sub>(The elements are sequential (i.e. 1, 2, 3, ...) but this is just for example. Also, though the number of matrices are two here, this number is just for example; sometimes it should be three or more.)</sub>

Trivially it is possible ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b4c5eaae7f7bc1c10cfb945486fae4c6)):

```
let mut v1: Vec<Vec<usize>> = vec![];
for i in 0..2 {
    v1.push(v.iter().skip(i * 4).take(4).copied().collect());
}

let mut v2: Vec<Vec<usize>> = vec![];
for i in 0..3 {
    v2.push(v.iter().skip(8 + i * 2).take(2).copied().collect());
}
```

But, is there a cleaner way? Here's the pseudo code I want:

```rust
let v1 = v.iter().every(4).take(2).collect();
let v2 = v.iter().skip(8).every(2).take(3).collect();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can split the initial vector into two slices and iterate each of them separately ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=56f93a1e604713b54d0536ea61a4c470)):

```rust
let (left, right) = v.split_at(8);
    
let v1 = left.chunks(4).map(|s| s.to_vec()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
let v2 = right.chunks(2).map(|s| s.to_vec()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Comment: Clean. Thank you. By the way, do you know a way to split a vector into three or more matrices? To be honest, I noticed I made the example shown in OP too simple... In competitive programming, I sometimes have to split an input vector into many matrices. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73669571/8776746) works even for such a situation but it depends on an external crate.

Answer (score 3):

If an external crate is allowed, you can use [`Itertools::chunks`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.chunks):

```rust
v.iter().chunks(4).into_iter().take(2).map(|l| l.copied().collect_vec()).collect()
```

([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0d5447db678b7e70ba6ecc18beebddd6))